# How to close jQuery Tools Overlay on click, no matter where?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tools

I've added the [Overlay effect](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/index.html) of jQuery Tools to my site, using the "Minimum Setup". Unfortunately when the user wants to close it, he must target this tiny circle on the upper right. Usability suffers this way. It would be far better if the user could simply click anywhere to close it.

Can I modify or add some code so it would close the overlay no matter where to user clicks? Or maybe when he clicks outside of the overlay? I couldn't find any notes on that in the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Or maybe when he clicks outside of the overlay?*
Check [the docs](http://jquerytools.org/documentation/overlay/index.html) ('Configuration' part):

**closeOnClick** (default: true)
*By default, overlays are closed when the mouse is clicked outside the overlay area. Setting this property to false suppresses this behaviour which is suitable for modal dialogs.*

I.e., this functionality is already enabled by default. If it's not working, you might want to show us your overlay configuration.

Comment: @BGerrissen I just happend to use this package recently, so I already knew where to look :)

Comment: Did exactly what they did here: http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/index.html - doesn't close at all by default when clicking outside the overlay. At least not on their own example site ;)

Comment: @BugAlert It seems you're right, but it works on [this example](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/styling.html) and on several others.

Answer (score 4):

@NikitaRybak The closeOnClick only works when you're using a expose/mask. I've modified the overlay code to work without a expose/mask..

Tidy the minified javascript..
locate this in the minified code:

```
b.closeOnClick && a(document).bind("click." + n, function(l) {
```

and insert this to the function instead

```
if (!a(l.target).hasClass('overlay') && !a(l.target).hasClass('apple') && !a(l.target).parents('.overlay', f).length && !a(l.target).parents('[rel="#' + a(f).attr('id') + '"]').length && !(a(l.target).attr('rel') == '#' + a(f).attr('id'))) { c.close(l); }
```

Now if you're using the apple effect, find this in the apple effect code:

```
b = h('<img src="' + b + '"/>');
```

and insert class="apple" so it becomes:

```
b = h('<img class="apple" src="' + b + '"/>');
```

Hope this helps if anyone needs it..

Comment: For me, this code opens and closes the overlay immediately. It seems there is some bug somewhere (I suspect jQuery library because the .parents(f) is behaving weirdly). The default overlay works fine in a different page. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try (quick and dirty):

```
$(document).click(function(){
    $('.simple_overlay:visible .close').click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

During my experiments I found out that even [official jQuery Tools standalone demo](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/index.htm) doesn't close overlay correctly. For example when I click under the overlayed image it closes but when I click on the right or left side outside of the overlay it doesn't close.

So, in my case I used next solution to close overlay on click anywhere on the document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function closeOverlay(){
        $('.overlay:visible .close').click();
    }
    document.addEventListener('click',closeOverlay,true);
</script>
```

May be it's dirty too but it works for me.

Comment: This one doesn't work for me because I want to exclude clicks inside the overlay itself.